# Storyboards + UIcollectionView : Ui shows up differently on iOS Simulator and on Device

Tags: ios, xcode, uicollectionview, uistoryboard

I am trying to make an app for iPhone5, 5c, 5s and 6 with Stroyboards, on Xcode 6, but I have run into a problem.

I am using a UICollectionView with a custom UICollectionViewCell and another custom views contained within the cell.

The problem is that when I look at storyboards then I see what I need, I run the app in iOS Simulator and the UI looks fine BUT when I test the same app on an iPhone 5c then the UI is mostly blank.

This is the image from the simulator:

[image]

And this is what I get on the iPhone:

[image: iPhone 5c Screenshot]

The individual items are objects of an UIViewControllerCell subclass.

The images in the simulator screenshot are a UIView (Contained within the UICollectionViewCell) that sets the frame of the images depending on the number of images i provide to it. So if I have 1 then it is displayed in the full area designated for the image as in the first item, it can display upto 4 images if there are more than 4 images then there is a label in place of the 4th image.

The thing that really seems strange to me is that, on the iPhone 5c, the UI shows up with just one image, so at least the UiCollectionView cell is visible, but then again the cell also does have a white background color, why didnt that appear?
This is the cod in the subclassed UICllectionViewCell's drawRect method:

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {    
self.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0f;
self.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 0.25f;
self.contentView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

self.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0.5f);
self.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0f;
self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.125f;
self.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
self.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds cornerRadius:self.contentView.layer.cornerRadius].CGPath;
```

}

I tried playing around with constraints but nothing happened, I turned autolayout off and still nothing.

Could someone please point out what is wrong and any fixes?

Thank You

**EDIT 1:**

I added `self.contentView.frame = self.frame;` to the top of drawRect and this is the result:

[image: self.contentView.frame = self.frame]

This is the code that I use to load the images, this is in the sublcassed UICollectionViewCell:

```
-(void) populate:(dataObject *) dataObject
```

{

```
NSArray *thumbsArray = dataObject.thumnails;
_thumbnailsView = [[ThumbnailsView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 139, 107)];
_tempThumbnailsView = [[ThumbnailsView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 139, 107)];
[_tempThumbnailsView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
_tempThumbnailsView.fileCount = bucket.fileCount;
_tempThumbnailsView.thumbnailsArray = thumbsArray;

[self.thumbnailsViewArea addSubview:_tempThumbnailsView];

self.title.text = dataObject.name;
```

}

"self.thumbnailsViewArea" is an IBOutlet to the view in the cell that will contain the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your autolayout attributes.

Comment: I turned off autolayout and for some reason it started displaying exactly what I saw on the storyboard. I also tried autolayouts and I figured out that it can work with that too but I dont have a need for auto layouts on this screen so I am not going for that.

I will wait a bit to see if I can at least get a better explanation otherwise I will mark your answer as accepted.